# search and select item in treeview tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, treeviewitem

I would like to create `search_function` to search data in treeview table.
On my code, I do need to click `search_button` to select data in treeview table following my 3 request below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

GUI = Tk()
GUI.geometry('1920x1080')

tree_view_frame = Frame(GUI)
tree_view_frame.pack()
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_view_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
header = ['Part No.', 'Name', 'Unit', 'Quan', 'Price','Total', 'Initial Total']
hdsize = [60,240,60,60,70,80,80]
aanchor = [W,W,E,E,E,E,E]
global product_table
product_table = ttk.Treeview(tree_view_frame, columns = header, show = 'headings', height = 20, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode="extended")
def treeview_sort_column(product_table, col, reverse):
    l = [(product_table.set(k, col), k) for k in product_table.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        product_table.move(k, '', index)
    product_table.heading(col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, not reverse))
for col in header:
    product_table.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, False))
product_table.pack()
tree_scroll.config(command = product_table.yview)
for h,s,a in zip(header, hdsize, aanchor):
    product_table.heading(h, text = h)
    product_table.column(h,width = s, anchor = a)

Nameget = StringVar()
E_namme = ttk.Entry(GUI,textvariable = Nameget)
E_namme.pack()

def Add_Product(event = None):
    product_table.insert('', 'end', value = ('', Nameget.get()))
B_Add_product = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "Add Product", command = Add_Product)
B_Add_product.pack()

def search_function():
    query = Nameget.get()
    selections = []
    for child in product_table.get_children():
        if query in product_table.item(child)['values'][1]:
            selections.append(child)
            product_table.selection_set(selections[0])
            product_table.focus(selections[0])
    product_table.focus_force()
search_button = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "search_button", width = 15, command = search_function)
search_button.pack()

GUI.mainloop()
```

1. for first click is to select the first result.
   [image]
2. second or next click is to select the next result until last result and do it as loop.
   [image]
3. auto scroll down the scrollbar to select the result when it not appear in the current page.
   [image]

In the current code, it can select only the first result and not auto scroll down the scrollbar.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `see` (ensures that item is visible)  and loop over.

Any data structure can assist here use `queue` or `dict` like the example below:

(It is good to use some OOP)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from collections import defaultdict

GUI = Tk()
GUI.geometry("1920x1080")

tree_view_frame = Frame(GUI)
tree_view_frame.pack()
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_view_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
header = ["Part No.", "Name", "Unit", "Quan", "Price", "Total", "Initial Total"]
hdsize = [60, 240, 60, 60, 70, 80, 80]
aanchor = [W, W, E, E, E, E, E]
global product_table


class ProductMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.selections = defaultdict(list)
        self.last_lookup = ""

    def treeview_sort_column(self, product_table, col, reverse):
        l = [(product_table.set(k, col), k) for k in product_table.get_children("")]
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)
        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
            product_table.move(k, "", index)
        product_table.heading(
            col,
            command=lambda _col=col: product_map.treeview_sort_column(
                product_table, _col, not reverse
            ),
        )

    def search_function(self):
        query = Nameget.get()
        if not query:
            return
        children = product_table.get_children()
        for child in children:
            curr = product_table.item(child)["values"][1]
            if query in curr and child not in self.selections[query]:
                self.selections[query].append(child)
                product_table.selection_set(child)
                product_table.focus(child)
                product_table.see(child)
                self.last_lookup = query
                return
            elif query != self.last_lookup:
                self.selections = defaultdict(list)

    def Add_Product(self, event=None):
        product_table.insert("", "end", value=("", Nameget.get()))


product_map = ProductMap()

product_table = ttk.Treeview(
    tree_view_frame,
    columns=header,
    show="headings",
    height=20,
    yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set,
    selectmode="extended",
)
for col in header:
    product_table.heading(
        col,
        text=col,
        command=lambda _col=col: product_map.treeview_sort_column(
            product_table, _col, False
        ),
    )
product_table.pack()
tree_scroll.config(command=product_table.yview)
for h, s, a in zip(header, hdsize, aanchor):
    product_table.heading(h, text=h)
    product_table.column(h, width=s, anchor=a)

Nameget = StringVar()
E_namme = ttk.Entry(GUI, textvariable=Nameget)
E_namme.pack()


B_Add_product = ttk.Button(GUI, text="Add Product", command=product_map.Add_Product)
B_Add_product.pack()


search_button = ttk.Button(
    GUI, text="search_button", width=15, command=product_map.search_function
)
search_button.pack()


GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, my third request is working but the second request is not fixed.

Comment: the code is moving the selected result from the first row to other. But what I need is moving only the selection line from result one to another.